# Burninate or synonym request for [if-this-then-that] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request, synonym-request

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74798747/get-if-condition-then-assign-value-else-assign-other-value-statement-in), which has a tag, called [if-this-then-that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/if-this-then-that). Apparently some other questions have this tag too. I don't see the sense of having this tag, while there already is an [if-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/if-statement) tag, hence this burninate or synonym request.

Comment: It's created for this question: [How does "If This Then That" implement access to third party user accounts (so called "Channels")?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26865509) which does name it specifically being related to [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/) - an automation build tool.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you posted this on Meta, there were exactly 13 questions tagged [if-this-then-that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/if-this-then-that) - certainly not a very long list and easy to go though. So, I did.

The earliest question is: [How does "If This Then That" implement access to third party user accounts (so called "Channels")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26865509/how-does-if-this-then-that-implement-access-to-third-party-user-accounts-so-c)

Which directly starts with:

> In the widely known [If This Then That app (IFTTT)](https://ifttt.com/) you can create workflows such as:
>
> > If I get an email with an attachment, add that attachment to Evernote.

Which is a pretty good introduction into what the tag was added for. There is an existing tool and it is on-topic.

I went through the shorty list of questions and removed the tag from the following ones which were not about IFTTT:

[Android run setup activity on first run only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28972547/android-run-setup-activity-on-first-run-only) 
[WordPress/php if statement within an if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33088719/wordpress-php-if-statement-within-an-if-statement) 
[I need help writing an if then statement using 2 criterion of ltv and credit score](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45948062/i-need-help-writing-an-if-then-statement-using-2-criterion-of-ltv-and-credit-sco) 
[If/Then in Access query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48994169/if-then-in-access-query) 
[Lua "if...then" statement unresponsive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49138938/lua-if-then-statement-unresponsive) 
[How to combine multiple If statements/Dlookup functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51697668/how-to-combine-multiple-if-statements-dlookup-functions) 
[Turn Switch statement into if/then and if/else statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53212453/turn-switch-statement-into-if-then-and-if-else-statement) 
[PL/SQL - Simple trigger, take from one column and IF-THEN-ELSE to another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61752534/pl-sql-simple-trigger-take-from-one-column-and-if-then-else-to-another-column) 
[Flag if there is a JOIN - SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63002200/flag-if-there-is-a-join-sql) 
[Get If (condition), then (assign value), else (assign other value) statement in Linear Programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74798747/get-if-condition-then-assign-value-else-assign-other-value-statement-in) \

This makes 10 questions. The other 3 I retagged with [ifttt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ifttt) which already existed:

[How does "If This Then That" implement access to third party user accounts (so called "Channels")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26865509/how-does-if-this-then-that-implement-access-to-third-party-user-accounts-so-c) 
[IFTTT: How to avoid URL shortening in Email-Channel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31088098/ifttt-how-to-avoid-url-shortening-in-email-channel) 
[How to send values to IFTTT trigger function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72108491/how-to-send-values-to-ifttt-trigger-function)

Writing this answer took longer than the actual cleanup.

Answer (score 10):

Looks like the off-topic uses have been removed so I merged this tag into [ifttt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ifttt) with a synonym to prevent it from being re-created

Answer (score 7):

There's something called [ifttt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ifttt) that is on-topic.

So maybe what we do instead is clean up the math-oriented questions along the way, and then synonymize [if-this-then-that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/if-this-then-that) to [ifttt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ifttt)?

Comment: AFAIK, the name "IFTTT" is the more well-known. I've certainly seen it for years. Today was the first time I found it stood for "if-this-then-that". So, seems like a decent solution.